# Holding down key in mac OS doesn't fire keypress event

Tags: javascript, html, macos, keyboard-events

I'm developing a simple console program with HTML/Javascript, where one of the basic requirements is that when a user holds down a key, it should repeat.

This works perfectly in Windows. When I hold down a key, it fires off multiple paired keydown/keypress events and I can send them off to the server. However, on OS X 10.9.5 in several browsers (Chrome, Safari, FF), only keydown continues to fire events. For example, when I hold down t, the following events fire:

```
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
keypress charCode=116, keyCode=0
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
keydown charCode=0, keyCode=84
```

Additionally, after a second or two, I see a pop up that allows me to select from several special characters. Google indicates that this is the "press and hold" feature, but I can't seem to find a way to disable it (for all users, not just for me).

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: fyi, `charCode` and `keyCode` are deprecated. Use `key` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown. Codes are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.key#Key_values

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Regardless, that's just the default log from keydown/keypress events.

Comment: Yes, but you might want to convert your code, because the approach is a bit different.